My Site is Appearing With a Spammy URL. Hacked or something else?
My site is digitalcruch dot com, and I am facing a low traffic problem. However, today, I noticed that my site is appearing on Google with a different URL. I searched the keyword 'digitalcruch sefirin kizi' and noticed another site with the same interface, and my site's logo is showing on the results.
I am not sure what is going on. What should I do now? Has someone hacked my site?

Also, my whole blog is available on site http://www.aneveningofgiving.org/index-7.html. I am not sure how this happened. So, I need help.

It looks like the aneveningofgiving.org has been pulled. (Its interesting to note it is also a new domain.

Isn't it a bit rude for you to complain of others copying your content when you claim to be "zealous to autonomous commenting and news gathering on internet culture and technology." - yet without siting sources?  (I was curious as to why a brand new site would outrank one established in 2019 - so I went digging a bit!)

It looks scraped rather than hacked, presumably for black hat SEO reasons.  It might be interesting to update some content on a page and see how long it takes for them to update theirs, though I doubt they will be doing anything more clever than scraping and re-uploading content.
It's also not been perfectly scraped - they are leaching rather than hosting a few images and a javascript file.  It would be technically possible for you to inject content into their site by serving them different versions of these files.
Google's page to report stolen content is here.  I'm not sure how useful doing so will be, because it is Google.
It may also be worth contacting namecheap.com, who appear to be the registrar for that domain, as it may be that one of their clients has been hacked and is not aware of it.
